# SQL Server Installer Update Cache management

Tags: sql-server

#### Is it safe to delete the old cumulative update directories from the `%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Update Cache` folders?

At least [this MSDN blog post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/beatrice_popa/archive/2013/02/12/questions-regarding-sql-server-installation-best-practices-the-files-we-can-delete-after-a-service-pack-is-installed-user-rights-and-how-many-instances-are-necessary-for-different-application.aspx) tells to leave anything in place in this directory. Is there any reference or supportability statement anywhere telling that I could or must not do that?

Rationale:
Due to the infamous ["incremental service model"](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/935897/en-us) for SQL Server, the SP1 for SQL Server 2012 has so far seen 9 cumulative update releases. The `Update Cache` directory is growing with each CU install and in environments where each CU since SP1 has been installed, it is at 9 GB already. We have the prospect of adding another 3 GB for the next 3 CU releases before the next SP is out ["later this year"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlreleaseservices/archive/2014/02/13/update-on-the-service-pack-plans-for-sql-server.aspx). Since the updates are "cumulative" I am trying to determine if it would be safe to delete all but the latest cumulative update directory from the Update Cache.

For a single server I probably would not bother, but the storage team members (who have not managed to implement storage-based deduplication yet) are crying frequently because of the growing storage requirements for SQL server instances and my office's carpet is soaking wet already.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/969052/en-us

I ran into something similar on a Windows XP machine when deleting Windows Update files, and essentially broke my .NET installation in a way that required a full reinstall to correct.

I saw another person on the Microsoft forums who was planning to offload the files to a SAN for day-to-day performance improvement, then move them back incrementally if updates failed. They didn't provide a follow-up with success or failure messages, however.

Comment: I assumed it was obvious that I did not want to delete *all* of the *Update Cache* but just the folders of those cumulative updates which have been superseded by new installations - i.e. after installing SQL Server 2012 SP1 CU13 the folders for CU1-12. Messing with the MSI caches is dangerous, I know that. After the latest CU installation, for the installer there never should be a reason to look into the older CUs since everything is contained in the latest one by definition.

Comment: You would think that, and that's what I thought. And, by definition, you're right, and I was right, too. What I'm saying is, I had exactly the same line of thought as you, I reinstalled the latest CUs, and that did NOT correct my issues, and my .NET remained partially broken, so tread lightly, back it up, and test thoroughly.